# Multiple Projects with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I have workspace inside of Eclipse which has 2 projects in it.

I want to reference project #2 from project #1, but when I go to Project -> Properties -> References, and tick the project that I want to add as a reference, I am still not able to instantiate the classes from project #2 inside of project #1.

This is a blackberry app, developed in Java and in Eclipse.

Project1
Launcher.java

Project2
Screen.java

I want to use `Screen scr = new Screen(); // located in Project1`

Comment: You made sure to import the appropriate package from Project 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the project to the build path so that the Eclipse Java compiler can see the other project.

1. Select Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Projects tab
2. Select **Add...**
3. Add "Project 1" and OK back to the workspace.

One other thing to check. If your classes are in the default package they won't be imported. If they are, try moving your classes to an explicit package.

For example:

```
import mypackage.Screen;

...
Screen scr = new Screen();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried this also.

Do i have to add it to a namespace or anything? (like .NET?)

Comment: actually, Now I'm getting an error saying "Error Preverifying class" - but I'm on the right track I think now. Cheers.